# Upgrade Jekyll 3 - jekyll-paginate

Tags: rubygems, jekyll

My blog is using Jekyll 2 and I've used pagination. However now that GitHub is moving to Jekyll 3[enter link description here](https://github.com/blog/2100-github-pages-now-faster-and-simpler-with-jekyll-3-0) and [Jekyll drop support for jekyll-paginate](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/upgrading/2-to-3/) I have problems upgrading.

The jekyll-paginate page says that it is retried as of Jekyll 3 and trying to bundle it with my other gems is creating a bunch of problems.

Any thoughts as too how to handle this? Are there any other pagination gems that works with Jekyll 3?

Comment: Any repository url to test ?

Comment: Sure - this is my blog repo: https://github.com/marcusoftnet/marcusoftnet.github.io

Comment: If you use `gh-pages` gem ( which includes jekyll-paginate ) in your Gemfile, you just have to add `gems: ["jekyll-paginate"]` in your _config.yml. It's the only difference between Jekyll 2 and 3.

Comment: Awesome that works! Now if I only can get my posts to show up ... https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/4010

Comment: Did you tried this https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/4010#issuecomment-167304631 ?

Comment: Yes, but the problem is that it's not showing up in my index.html

Comment: If you use the flag `--safe ` to running Jekyll it won't work. Try `bundle exec jekyll serve` and check how it goes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Jekyll 3.0 is no more supporting paginate by default. You have to use ruby gems to paginate.

So add `gems: [jekyll-paginate]` to your **_config.yml** file.

Answer (score 0):

You can also add to _config.yml

## Gems

gems: [jekyll-paginate]

paginate: 5

paginate_path: "page:num"